# Convert string to symbol-able in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Symbols are usually represented as such

```
:book_author_title
```

but if I have a string:

```
"Book Author Title"
```

is there a built in way in rails/ruby to convert it into a symbol where I can use the `:`  notation without just doing a raw string regex replace?

Comment: Rather than conversion, you migh be interested in [indifferent access - methods working equally for both string and symbol parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780817).

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Rails got `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String::Inflections` module that provides such methods. They're all worth looking at. For your example:

```
'Book Author Title'.parameterize.underscore.to_sym # :book_author_title
```

Comment: this works really well! you could have any words weather or not they where Capitalized. the parameterize will sort it out.

Comment: is there any way to reverse this, without using gsub ?

Comment: @Zack `.to_s` and `.humanize` should do the job unless you need to preserve full capitalization.

Comment: A good way to approach converting anything is to be able to do and undo an operation.  .to_sym can convert one direction (from string to symbol), and .to_s can convert (from symbol to string). and if you are dealing with an array consider .map(&:to_sym)   or .map(&to_s) to convert all elements.

Comment: parameterize('_').to_sym is a bit shorter than parameterize.underscore.to_sym.

Comment: In rails 6 at least, `parameterize('_')` does not work. It needs to be `parameterize(separator: '_')` - so you may as well just use `parameterize.underscore.to_sym`

Answer (score 248):

from: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000809

```
str.intern => symbol
str.to_sym => symbol
```

Returns the Symbol corresponding to `str`, creating the symbol if it did not previously exist. See `Symbol#id2name`.

```
"Koala".intern         #=> :Koala
s = 'cat'.to_sym       #=> :cat
s == :cat              #=> true
s = '@cat'.to_sym      #=> :@cat
s == :@cat             #=> true
```

This can also be used to create symbols that cannot be represented using the `:xxx` notation.

```
'cat and dog'.to_sym   #=> :"cat and dog"
```

But for your example ...

```
"Book Author Title".gsub(/\s+/, "_").downcase.to_sym
```

should go ;)

Comment: The original poster may have been happy with the Rails answer, but this post answers the actual question asked.

Comment: It is not true that "[`to_sym`] can also be used to create symbols that cannot be represented using the :xxx notation". `:'cat and dog'` is the same as `'cat and dog'.to_sym`.

Comment: One can even do such outlandish things as `:"cat and dog\n on a new line"` without the need for `to_sym`.

Comment: I feel that `"Some Madness!!!!".gsub(/\s+/,"_").gsub(/\W+/,"").downcase.to_sym`  Should do the trick.   You don't want non-word characters in your symbol.

Comment: What is the difference between `.intern` and `.to_sym`?

Comment: The question was about conversion in Ruby, not Rails. This is a correct answer.

Answer (score 29):

```
"Book Author Title".parameterize('_').to_sym
=> :book_author_title
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

parameterize is a rails method, and it lets you choose what you want the separator to be. It is a dash "-" by default.

Answer (score 16):

intern → symbol
Returns the Symbol corresponding to str, creating the symbol if it did not previously exist

```
"edition".intern # :edition
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-intern

Comment: Like this one since my string.to_sym solution give me a security warning :)

Comment: It's the same security concern since it uses the same method under the hood, they are aliases

Answer (score 13):

In Rails you can do this using `underscore` method:

```
"Book Author Title".delete(' ').underscore.to_sym
=> :book_author_title
```

The simpler code is using regex (works with Ruby):

```
"Book Author Title".downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "_").to_sym
=> :book_author_title
```

Comment: this will only work if all the words start with a capital, if it was "my fat Dog" it will return :myfat_dog.

Answer (score 12):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
:"Book Author Title"
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

This is not answering the question itself, but I found this question searching for the solution to convert a string to symbol and use it on a hash.

```rb
hsh = Hash.new
str_to_symbol = "Book Author Title".downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "_").to_sym
hsh[str_to_symbol] = 10
p hsh
# => {book_author_title: 10}
```

Hope it helps someone like me!