# Hash with indifferent access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a non-Rails project in which I am loading some settings from a YAML file:

```ruby
config = YAML::load File.open("#{LOG_ROOT}/config/database.yml")
```

I can only access this hash like `config["host"]`, `config["username"]` etc.

I want indifferent access so I can use both `:host` and `"host"`.

The reason is, that one of the gems in the project to which I am passing this hash seems to be accessing it using symbols and it fails currently.

What is the best way to create a hash with indifferent access in this scenario?

Comment: Even if you're not using rails is there any reason why you just couldn't `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'`, and there's your solution?

Comment: I haven't installed active_support gem and was wondering should I be installing it just to get this feature.

Comment: If you don't want to, copy/paste the code into your own hash with indifferent access class. I haven't looked at Rails' solution, but I've written one myself before, can't be more than 50 LOC.

Comment: I thought about that too..checking here to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @josnidhin: you'd prefer not to use the library that supports it (active_support) nor copy the isolated method code into your project. I am afraid we run out of options here :-)

Comment: I am new to ruby so thought why not check with the community just in case I have missed something. I am open to copying.

Comment: While it's a convenience to be able to use both `hash['foo']` and `hash[:foo]`, it's not good programming practice to intersperse both throughout your code. Pick one style or the other and stick with it. Symbols have advantages as far as speed and memory use, but the difference is small in normal programs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let the config hash return the value for the stringified version of the key:

```
config = {"host"=>"value1", "Username"=>"Tom"}
config.default_proc = proc{|h, k| h.key?(k.to_s) ? h[k.to_s] : nil}
p config[:host] #=> "value1"
```

The `default_proc` runs everytime when a key is not found in the hash. Note this is only half of indifferent access: `config["host"]` will result in nil if the key `:host` is present. If that has to work too:

```
config.default_proc = proc do |h, k|
   case k
     when String then sym = k.to_sym; h[sym] if h.key?(sym)
     when Symbol then str = k.to_s; h[str] if h.key?(str)
   end
end
```

See the comments about limitations of this approach (tltr: separate values for `:a` and `'a'` are possible, does not take into account `Hash.delete` and others).

Comment: This will work for access via `[]` but not for things like `delete` where you will have to give the correct version of the key. Just so you are aware.

Comment: Note also, that it will not prevent someone from adding two keys: 'host' and :host with different values assigned! If you have key 'host' in your Hash and add key :host the second one will not overwrite the first one!

Answer (score 54):

You lose nothing except a few kB of disk space by installing the Active Support gem. In your code, you require only the function you want:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
```

That way, you can be sure you are not getting anything else to mess up your namespace.

Comment: Yes, but then things like this break :( -- "%{version}" % {version: 5}.with_indifferent_access.to_hash because I'm guessing internally strings as used instead of symbols :(

Comment: Interesting observation. You actually taught me a trick I didn't even know here :-), and I see, it indeed does not work with those ActiveSupport indifferent hashes. On the short notice, I am unable to say whether this can be remedied, but you would do a good deed for the Ruby community if you would to submit a ticket to this effect to the ActiveSupport devs.