# Ruby turn string into symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a view helper that has a size argument ( e.g.   `func(size)`). The issue is that this size has to be used in the function as a symbol. For example, if I pass in `'medium'` into the `func` I need it to be converted to `:medium`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to a symbol?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this:

If your string has no spaces, you can simply to this:

`"medium".to_sym => :medium`

If your string has spaces, you should do this:

`"medium thing".gsub(/\s+/,"_").downcase.to_sym => :medium_thing`

Or if you are using Rails:

`"medium thing".parameterize.underscore.to_sym => :medium_thing`

References: [Convert string to symbol-able in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004491/convert-string-to-symbol-able-in-ruby)

Comment: Technically you don't need to convert the spaces to anything.

Comment: Technically yes but you would get :"a symbol like this" (1.9.3)

Comment: Be aware that symbols don't get garbage collected before ruby 2.2. So if you do to_sym on dynamic strings, your application will run out of memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a string to symbol with this:

```
string = "something"
symbol = :"#{string}"
```

Comment: or just `string.to_sym`

Answer (score 1):

Or just

```
a = :'string'
# => :string
```