# makefile pass variable to vagrantfile and start the vagrant VM

Tags: shell, makefile, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm writing the automated deployment plan for the project. I plan to use makefile to control the vagrant vm and its operations. I want to place all user option configurations in the makefile, including some vagrantfile configuration parameters, such as CPU, IP, and the like. But how do I pass makefile parameters to vagrantfile? 
I test to use shell

```
CPU_NUM ?= 3

init:
    vagrant_cpu= $(CPU_NUM ) vagrant up
```

But I didn't know vagrantfile how to obtain it

I would very appreciate it if you guys can tell me how to achieve it that parameters are passed from the makefile to vagrantfile

Answer (score 1):

Makefile is nice, but why not just use shell scripts for general-purpose scripting? But, to actually answer your question:

The command where you set the environment variable is wrong, the `=` must not have a space on either side. Change it to:

```
init:
    vagrant_cpu=$(CPU_NUM) vagrant up
```

A `Vagrantfile` is [just a Ruby script](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/). This means that you can access environment variables the same way you would in Ruby, using [`ENV`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/ENV.html). In your `Vagrantfile`, you could have something like:

```rb
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.memory = 1024
  v.cpus = ENV["vagrant_cpu"].to_i
end
```

Note `to_i` to convert to integer.

Comment: So, If the variable is a string, then to_? type

Comment: @moluzhui If the variable is a string, just use `ENV["whatever"]` directly. All environment variables are strings, so you only need to convert them if you need a different type.

Comment: Bily. In fact, this is not the case, I use `cloud_name=$(CLOUD_NAME) vagrant up` to pass cloud_name `config.vm.define :ENV["cloud_name"] do |node_conf|`.The result is `The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
an invalid or undefined variable. Message: undefined method `to_sym'`

Comment: Ah, in that place you need a symbol ([`config.vm.define` docs](https://friendsofvagrant.github.io/v1/docs/config/vm/define.html)). The `:` only works to convert a literal to a symbol ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004491/convert-string-to-symbol-able-in-ruby)). You need `config.vm.define ENV["cloud_name"].to_sym do |node_conf|` – might even work without the `.to_sym`, but definitely cannot have the `:`.

Comment: if I have many variables,  this way seems to be complex. Is there an easier way to do this? I've tried to use `prerequisites`  to place variables uniformly, but that doesn't work